# Visa expiry and re issue

Tags: visas, schengen

I got schengen visa valid from 15.03.15 to the 13.04.15. My visiting plan was during this period. Unfortunately I can't use this visa, my visiting schedule changed to May 2015. Can I submit again visa application after this expire? Is there any penalty for this. Any chance to extend this period or re-issue?

Comment: You do realise that TSE is not a visa office support website?

Answer (score 1):

They are unlikely to extend leave on your existing visa if you have not yet entered Schengen with it and it would result in your obtaining more leave than what they wanted to issue.

Based upon what you wrote, you still have 29/30 days of unspent leave so you can apply again and simultaneously request cancellation of your existing visa.  Voluntary cancellation has no effect on future applications.

For your other questions...

- You do not have to wait until your current visa expires to submit a
  fresh application as long as you are cancelling your existing visa;
- There is no penalty.